# Magento 1.5 disable cache for template

Tags: templates, caching, magento

How do I disable the cache only for the one template that I need.

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

As I know this meta tag is just for browser. If you want to disable caching of certain block (that in general means template) you need to add to the constructor of this block following lines:

```
$this->addData(array(
    'cache_lifetime'=> null,
));
```

It will look like something like this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'=> null,
    ));
}
```

It worked for me when I removed footer block from caching
Note: this method is not enough in Magento EE with FPC

Comment: How to achieve this then with magento EE ?